# Make an image div active on click inside blade for each loop using carousel

Tags: php, html, css, laravel-blade

I have lopping through with a foreach loop to print out images one by one.
Clicking the `li` tag is supposed to make the `.carousel` div active.
However, i can't get that to work.

below is the my code.

```html
<div id="product_details_slider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
   <ol class="carousel-indicators" style="width:100%;overflow:auto;">
       @if ($product->images->count() > 0)
       @php
       $i = 0;
       @endphp
       @foreach($product->images as $image)
       <li class="" 
          data-target="#product_details_slider" 
          data-slide-to="{{ $i++ }}" 
          style="background-image: url({{ '/storage/'.$image->full }} );float:left;">
       </li>
       @endforeach
       @endif
   </ol>
   
   <div class="carousel-inner">
       @if ($product->images->count() > 0)
       @php
       $id = 0;
       @endphp
       <div class="carousel-item active">
           <a class="gallery_img" href="{{ '/storage/'.$product->images->first()->full }}">
               <img 
                  class="d-block w-100" 
                  src="{{ '/storage/'.$product->images->first()->full }}" 
                  alt="First slide">
           </a>
       </div>
       @else

       @endif
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: where are the event listeners / handlers or the onclicks?

Comment: i do not know how to go about it

Comment: Can you provide some JavaScript/jQuery code?